# .getEmail() method for DriveApp and SpreadsheetApp for Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to Google Scripts for Applications and am trying to get an array of the users that can edit a Google spreadsheet.  When I do `DriveApp.getFileById('xxxxxx').getEditors()`...it returns an array of users.  When I run the `.getName()` method on each item in the array, it returns the names.  However, when the run the `.getEmail()` method on each item, it does not return the email address for each user.

I tried opening the spreadsheet with `SpreadsheetApp.openFileById('xxxxxx').getEditors()`...and with this array I was able to run the `.getEmail()` method on each item and get the email addresses.

What is the difference between these `.getEmail()` methods?  Why can I seem to get the emails from the SpreadsheetApp, but not the DriveApp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DriveApp as well as the drive api protect collaborator's emails. You no longer can get them.
You have to use the older apis which will eventually be deprecated.
In the new api you can only tell the users email if you previously shared something with them and you saved their permissionId. See the drive api docs for more.